# Photo grid only displaying some images

Tags: jquery, html, css, gallery, photos

I have a specifically strange issues happening with my photo grid.

What I am trying to do is have a mansory grid that displays a caption on hover.

When I get the images to wrap correctly *with* the captions working as they should the middle and right column images don't display. Only the background color shows in it's place.

If you resize the window to be 1 col or view the page on a mobile device, it shows all the images in single order.

I have no idea why this would happen but I've edited the mansory layout a few different ways but everything this seems to happen.

The latest layout is shown here: http://s213258.gridserver.com/photos.html

Any suggestions are hugely appreciated!

Comment: I've got all the site files over on Github - this specific page is the "photos.html" page

Answer (score 0):

I tested this, and for some strange reason the "column-count" property doesn't render images properly on 2nd and 3rd column (after a little research, this seems to be a chrome bug)!

There is this [plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/) that does the job well and it's simple to setup.

Hope it helps!